# CakePHP Custom Route Classes - How to Pass Arguments?

Tags: cakephp, routes, cakephp-2.0

I've created a custom route class and I want to be able to pass in settings/options to the constructor so that it's configurable. Can this be done?

**Documentation for Custom Route Classes:**

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#custom-route-classes

**My custom route class:**

https://github.com/Signified/CakePHP-Model-Route-Class

Answer (score 0):

You can probably just pass any settings/options you might have in the options of your Router::connect function.

```
App::import('Lib', 'ModelRoute');
Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display'),
    Array('routeClass' => 'ModelRoute',
          'someMoreOptions' => 'OptionValue' ));
```

Then you can retrieve the key someMoreOptions in your constructor

```
public function __construct($settings = array())
    {
        $this->settings = Set::merge($this->settings, $settings);
        // Now you can do something with the option passed.
        if(isset($this->settings['someMoreOptions'])
            DoSomethingWith($this->settings['someMoreOptions']);
    }
```