# dynamic html redirects using cakephp routers

Tags: cakephp, redirect, routes

dynamic html redirects  using routers

in the beginning I had no categories and all of my pages were root

example:

```
   http://domain/somepage
```

This was great, but as my content over the years grew I need to categorize my content

so I added some routes see below 
//routes.php

```
Router::connect(

"/:category/:slug",
array('controller' => 'controllername', 'action' => 'view'),
       array( 

            'name'=>'[-A-Z0-9]+', 

           'pass' => array('category','slug')



          ) 

        );
```

//end
this works great and accomplished what I needed to do, but there is one problem  the search engines .I need to write 301's for all of my links and I have over 8K pages.

The solution cakesphp's Router::redirect

The issue I am now having is I cant figurer out how to redirect  my old links.  I can for example redirect all of the links to one category, but that wont cut it. I need to redirect all of my links to the new location.

I am trying to use  routes.php router :: redirect

if I do this my code it redirects to the category, but not the slug

```
   Router::redirect(
'/:slug/*',
  array(
  'pass' => array('category/:slug'))
```

result

```
  http://domain/category/
```

how can I get cake to redirect to

```
  http://domain/category/slug  ?

  instead of  http://domain/category/
```

I had all of my links pointing to the root directory
   `http://domain/somepage
        http://domain/anotherpage
        http://domain/ect`

I needed to add categories

such as

```
`
     http://domain.com/phones/samsung.php
     http://domain.com/books/cakephp.php
```

`

I didn’t want to use .htaccees file because

My hosing provide limits me to 100 redirects

and i have over 8K links i need to redirect

I am trying to use cakes router ::redirect function in the routes.php file.

the below code works only for one category it doesn’t do it dynamically like I would like it too. 
I tried to create a router class that would do this for me like you suggested, but to be honest with you I am not an expert in cakephp. Its easy to learn and a great framework I just dont know how to make my own classes or components yet. I just haven’t found good documentation to do this yet.

```
 //routes.php

  $move='category/'. stripslashes_deep ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);             Router::redirect('/:slug/*',$move, array('status' => 302)); code
```

Comment: Use a custom route class.

See [this article](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8089273/cakephp-custom-route-classes-how-to-pass-arguments)

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to use a custom route class.

Custom routing extends the CakeRoute class and will allow you to return/add/modify parameters that are passed over.

[CakePHP Custom Route Classes - How to Pass Arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8089273/cakephp-custom-route-classes-how-to-pass-arguments)

Comment: well im pretty new to cake, but i will try it. I guess it's a good time to learn the api so i can start writing my own classes.

Comment: I couldn’t get my class to work so i did this in the router.php file 

I am pretty sure there is another way. If anyone has a solution i would appreciate it
`code
 $move='category/'. stripslashes_deep     ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    Router::redirect('/:slug/*',$move, array('status' => 302)); code`

Comment: Tell me what you are trying to do, and I will see if i can help out

Comment: My post was to long so i had to edit the above post. I Hope this helps you